# PHP file losing formatting after FTP upload

Tags: php, ftp, winscp

I am using WinSCP to transfer files to an FTP site.  I have a situation currently where one specific file within a folder loses all of its formatting when it is uploaded causing the PHP file to no longer work.

All other PHP files within the folder work correctly when uploaded.

I can't understand why just one file could be affected in this way.  Can anyone shed any light on the situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "losing formatting"? A PHP engine could parse your script whether all of code is on one line with no spaces, or there are 50 linebreaks between each line of code.

Comment: Are you sure?  What happens when comments within your code merge with valid commands to create invalid ones?

Comment: That's why I never use `//` comments in PHP. `/*  comment */` wouldn't have any issue with everything on one line or any other format

Comment: Thanks for the tip, any thoughts on the cause of the formatting issue?

Comment: No idea, what do you mean by it's loosing formatting?

Comment: Line breaks are gone, everything is on one line

Comment: Odd, maybe try a different ftp program like FileZilla?

Comment: Change your binary/ascii setting.  This might shed some light (read the last bit near the bottom).  Line breaks get treated differently depending on transfer mode.  http://www.editpadpro.com/tricklinebreak.html - just to add, as stated, it shouldn't cause your scripts to fail.

Comment: To repeat @mituw16's question: What do mean by loosing formatting? How do you check that a file lost formatting? Do you download it back and open in local editor? What editor? Or do you open it using remote editor? (Such as `vi` on console)

Answer (score 1):

The file was probably transferd via [ASCII mode](https://superuser.com/questions/4401/whats-the-point-of-ascii-mode-in-ftp) which will modify the encoding and the line endings of the file.

Comment: Yep I get that, but my question is why would just one file inside a folder be affected?

Comment: Maybe something about the file triggered ASCII or BINARY mode. Could be the filename or the file content. Maybe it was saved with Windows line endings, while all other files were saved with Unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not stated what exactly do you mean by "losing formatting", it's difficult to answer, anyway:

As per src's answer, if the line endings change due to ASCII/text mode transfers, the resulting converted file can be perceived as if it lost formatting, if opened in an editor that does not support the target line endings. Though that hardly explains why there's only one affected file. *Although can WinSCP technically choose a different transfer mode for example based on a file size or modification timestamp, if configured so, I doubt you did.* Also note that WinSCP defaults to binary transfer mode. It would help if you state what transfer mode do you actually use with WinSCP. Definitive source for this information is WinSCP session log file. Also sharing relevant part of a log file would also help with investigation.

Another possibility is that the affected source file was created with a different line endings in the first place (like in a different editor than you use usually). As such the problem would have nothing to do with transfer mode, or WinSCP. And the difference is possibly revealed only after you open the files using a third editor on the remote side that supports only one of the line ending formats.

Though in both of these cases, the file should still work in PHP, as PHP supports both Unix and Windows line endings. Possibly the source file has such a strange format that during ASCII/text mode transfer, the server got confused and converted the file incorrectly. But that's just a wild guess.

Again, we need more information to help you.